# Ignoring input on portion of a touch pad

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I bought a laptop that's almost perfect, with a value that's difficult to believe. But for some reason, I'm guessing aesthetics, there are no buttons. You just click hard on the pad to initiate a click. The problem is that this often causes the click to be registered as 450px south-west or south-east. This seems to be caused by the act of clicking in itself. The touchpad is fine otherwise.

The question is, whether it's possible in Linux to ignore touch pad input from  a region of the touch pad, so that the region that's used as buttons, are not used for touch input?

If anyone has a fix for this, they can sell this laptop with 100% profit.

Comment: Assuming this is X11, which input driver are you using – "xf86-input-libinput" or "xf86-input-synaptics"? What is the laptop model, and what touchpad model does it show under `xinput list`?

Answer (score 0):

Libinput (usually available as `xf86-input-libinput` or `xserver-xorg-input-libinput`) automatically recognizes most [clickpad](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/clickpad-softbuttons.html) models and will **already** ignore touches if they start within the "button area" (such touchpads generally have painted-on buttons).

If you use X11, make sure you have the Libinput module installed and *do not* have the older "Synaptics" driver installed (`[...]-input-synaptics`); these days it's provided only as an alternative for certain old devices so it will override libinput when installed. (Run `xinput list-props "<device name>"` to check whether the touchpad is handled by libinput, synaptics, or evdev.)

---

Many relatively-new laptops have the touchpad connected in two ways: they emulate a PS/2 mouse at first, until the driver tells it to switch over to a more flexible protocol such as RMI/SMBus/I2C. The PS/2 emulation makes the touchpad work even without drivers, but at the cost of significantly worse precision and lack of multitouch support.

For some manufacturers (especially Synaptics) the Linux driver only switches protocols if the model is found in the 'known good' list. Run `dmesg` and check if it mentions "intertouch" or similar.

---

Finally, if libinput is already active but the touchpad just outright generates bogus events, report that to [libinput developers](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/issues).